# Bootstrap-Vue - Nav tabs not active for children on router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

Versions:

```
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.27",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-router": "^3.0.3",
```

My vue-router has children on the `/app/groups` route. Within the children, I created `<b-nav pills>` in order to navigate `groups` however the `tabs` are not showing up as `.active`. I'm using `params` on the routes, not sure if this affects it. Any ideas?

**GroupContainer.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container class="pt-3">
      <b-nav pills align="center">
        <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'group.edit', params: { id: this.$route.params.id }}" >Group</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'group.users', params: { id: this.$route.params.id }}" >Users</b-nav-item>
      </b-nav>
    </b-container>
    <DefaultPage title="Group name" subtitle="Settings">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </DefaultPage>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DefaultPage from '../layouts/DefaultPage.vue'

export default {
  name: 'GroupContainer',
  components: {
    DefaultPage
  }
}
</script>
```

**router.js**

```js
{ path: "/app/group", component: GroupContainer,
    children: [
      { path: "", component: NotFound },
      { path: ":id", name: "group.edit", component: GroupEdit },
      { path: ":id/delete", name: "group.delete", component: GroupDelete },
      { path: ":id/users", name: "group.users",  component: GroupUsers },
      { path: ":id/users/:userID", name: "group.users.edit", component: GroupEditUser },
      { path: ":id/users/:userID/delete", name: "group.users.delete", component: GroupDeleteUser },
      { path: ":id/add-user", name: "group.addUser", component: GroupAddUser }, 
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `active-class` or `exact-active-class` prop, and set it to `'active'`

```html
  <b-nav pills align="center">
    <b-nav-item
       :to="{ name: 'group.edit', params: { id: this.$route.params.id }}"
       :exact-active-class="active"
    >Group</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item
      :to="{ name: 'group.users', params: { id: this.$route.params.id }}"
      :exact-active-class="active"
    >Users</b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
```

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/router-links